# Unable to test the session[:user_id] value set in POST #create in SessionsController spec with RSpec/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, rspec, controller

I'm struggling with how to correctly test the POST #create action in the SessionsController. I've attempted to stub authentication. My assumption is that a valid test should test that the session[:user_id] is in fact equal to the @user.id value, after the post :create action is executed. However, I get nil returned for session[:user_id].

Mocks, stubs, etc are still a bit new to me. The stub for authentication seems pretty straightforward. However, why can't I get the session value to be returned when I run this test?

The test for valid authentication is currently failing (though it works in actual practice - i.e. I can sign in to the app). This is the one I'm concerned with. The second test (invalid password) is passing, and seems fine. All of my other session controller specs are passing.

Here's the portion of my sessions_controller_spec.rb file that deals with the session creation via POST #create:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe SessionsController, type: :controller do
 describe "POST #create" do
  context "where authentication is valid" do
   it "creates a new session with a welcome message" do
    @user = create(User, id: 1)
    allow(@user).to receive(:authenticate).and_return @user

    post :create, email: "test@example.com", password: "secret1234"

    expect(session[:user_id]).to eq @user.id
    expect(flash[:notice]).to match("Welcome back!")
  end
 end

 context "where password is invalid" do
  it "re-renders the signin page with an alert message" do
    user = create(:user)

    post :create, session: { email: user.email, password: 'invalid' }

    expect(response).to render_template :new
    expect(flash[:alert]).to match("Incorrect email/password combination!")
   end
  end
 end

 # CODE FOR OTHER TESTS OMITTED

end
```

This is my sessions_controller.rb file:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    if user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      flash[:notice] = "Welcome back!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Incorrect email/password combination!"
      render :new
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to new_session_path, notice: "Signed Out!"
  end
end
```

The test returns the following error:

```
 1) SessionsController POST #create where authentication is valid creates a new session with a welcome message
     Failure/Error: expect(session[:user_id]).to eq @user.id

       expected: 1
            got: nil

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:12:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:42:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Is there a better, or preferred, way to test that the SessionsController successfully creates the session and sets the session[:user_id] value?

Comments, code critiques, etc, are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't stub the method correctly:

```
allow(@user).to receive(:authenticate).and_return @user
```

In the controller you are calling `authenticate` on a class, not the instance. The line above should be:

```
allow(User).to receive(:authenticate).and_return @user
```